# How many maximum height AVL trees given height?

Tags: data-structures, trees, search-trees, avl-trees

I am having some trouble finding a recursive formula for finding the number of maximum height AVL trees of height h. Height 0 has 1, height 1 has 2, height 2 has 4, height 3 has 8, etc. is that correct?

Comment: "How many maximum height AVL trees given height?" should be "How many AVL trees with given height?". "the number of maximum height AVL trees of height h" should be "the number of AVL trees of height $h$". Please edit the question.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/26046/91753) answer your question?